# thread objects .. destruction

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

So I have been fiddling with std::thread lately, and I encountered the following situation:-
First of all, my goal is to have a thread perform an operation on an object. To illustrate, following is a simple code that construct a thread to set a member variable via a member function of an object. The problem is when this code is executed, memory will be increasingly consumed as threads spawned in the while loop. I don't understand this behavior; shouldn't the thread be destructed once it goes out of scope and hence memory consumed by the program remains constant as the *while* loops?

```
 #include <thread>    
   using namespace std;  
   class foo  
   {  
      public:  
      int x;  
      void set()  
      {
         x = 1;  
      }  
   };  

   int main()   
   {   
      while(true)   
      {   
         foo f;   
         thread t(&foo::set, &f);   
         t.join();   
      }   
      return 0;   
   }
```

EDIT: I am executing this program using MinGW64 under windows  7. The rate of memory consumed by the above code is approximately 1 megabyte per second.

Comment: For me your program tops out at 316Kb and 115% cpu.  No memory leak.  Everything looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you suggest that memory consumption increases until 316KB, meaning memory consumption is not constant, could you justify this.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem either. It appears to be a constant level of memory and CPU from Resource Monitor.

Comment: This is really odd, I kept the program running for a while and currently it occupies 1.4G bytes and increasing.